# Nav bar doesn't display when I use the <Link> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-router

I changed the anchor tag to the Link tag and the whole component doesn't display. It is note worthy that I had used the anchor tag and it was properly rendered. However, after changing to the Link tag nothing gets displayed again. Below is what my code looks like:

Navbar component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';


class Navbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div className="Navbar">
            <ul className="navbar-list">
                <li className="active"><Link to={"/home"}>Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link to={"/about"}>About Us</Link></li>
                <li><Link to={"/pricing"}>Pricing</Link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
    }
}


export default Navbar
```

css

```
.navbar-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;

}

.navbar-list li{
float: left;
}

.navbar-list li Link {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-list li Link:hover{
  background-color: #111 ;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

App.js file

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Is `NavBar` being rendered within a `Router`? I believe it does in order for the `Link`s to be renderable. Do you see any react warnings in console?

Comment: You should check react-router version you are using. And read the documentation for corresponding version.
Also replace "Link" with "a" in your css. After rendering Link exists as anchor tag in dom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some issue in `Link` from `react-router`
Instead try using

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
```

You code will look like this:

in dependencies of your package.json and do `npm i`: include:

```
    "react-router-dom": "5.0.0",
```

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
<Router>
        <Navbar />
<Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';


class Navbar extends Component {

    render() {
        return (

            <div className="Navbar">
                <ul className="navbar-list">
                    <li className="active"><NavLink to={"/home"}>Home</NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink to={"/about"}>About Us</NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink to={"/pricing"}>Pricing</NavLink></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        )
    }
}


export default Navbar;
```

Comment: 'react-router' does not contain an export named 'Link' #6207 
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6207 link

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to change To prop on string like this :

```
<Link to="/pricing">Pricing</Link>
```

Another thing u can try is install react-router-dom instead of react-router.